# Why don't my laptop specs match the ones on the internet?

Tags: laptop, netbook

I bought a laptop without having any knowlege on what to buy. I saw an Asus Eee PC 1215T and bought it immediately.

After a few days of use, I decided to look at the goodness of this laptop. Then I found out that some of my laptop don't match the specs of the same laptop on the net.

My laptop is an Asus Eee PC 1215T and the specs are:

```
AMD 105 processor
2GB RAM
300gb HDD
ATI mobility radeon HD 4250
Etc.
```

And the Asus Eee PC 1215T I saw on the net is:

```
AMD Athlon II Neo K125 @ 1.7GHz
ATI Radeon HD 4225
2GB DDR2 RAM
250GB HDD
```

Why is that they have different specs? And if it's possible to replace my AMD v105 processor into an AMD Athlon II Neo K125 @ 1.7GHz, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look on the website of the seller that you bought the netbook from or just a random web site ? For instance here: http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Asus-Eee-PC-1215T-Netbook.41488.0.html the netbook has the same specs yours has.

Take into account that configurations can be different for different countries, or can even be different from one vendor to another.

Secondly, you can upgrade the CPU of a laptop. But what you have is not a laptop but a netbook and usually netbooks have the CPU on their motherboard and that means that you can only change it and that you can't upgrade it separately.

Comment: so in other words... i can replace mg amd v105 processor into a AMD Athlon II Neo K125 @ 1.7GHz??

Comment: no. you have a notebook, for notebooks it is impossible to change the processor

Comment: netbook CPUs are soldered on the the motherboard

Comment: ohh :( thanx everyone